# How to decrease React-Native android App Size

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

For my react native android app, size of codes I have written is only 12KB

But package generated is of size 7.9MB. How can i decrease that.

As per **[Documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)** for react native, I have already enbabled proguard on file `app_root/android/app/proguard-rules.pro` but size of didn't decrease

```
...
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}
...
```

Is there a solution available for this?

Comment: what about `minifyEnabled false`

Comment: false was there by default, that doesnt work

Comment: now the size is 30mb and for separate architectures 9mb

Answer (score 6):

React Native app APKs include JSCore binaries for x86 and ARM. If you don't need x86 you could reduce the size to 3-4 MB.

1)In your app/build.gradle set

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```

2)remove x86 from abiFilters

this  helped me in reducing size from 7.8 mb to 4.5MB

Comment: How to remove x86 from abiFilters?

Comment: I think the line `abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"` in `android.defaultConfig.ndk`in the same file should simply be changed to `abiFilters "armeabi-v7a`

Answer (score 3):

Android devices support two major device artitectures **armebi** and **x86**. By default RN builds the native librariers for both these artitectures into the same apk.

Open up android/app/build.gradle :

Set **def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true**,

this would enable Progaurd to compress the Java Bytecode. This reduces the app size by a lil bit

And,

Set def **enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true** .

And check in android/app/build/outputs/apk/  - you will receive two apk files for armebi and x86 with approx half size of original apk.

Comment: Nice Answer. But one question... Is there an overview which devices support x86 and which armebi.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of techniques in order to reduce your APK size:

1. Split your app by architecture, you can split your APK by a list of well-known architectures: armeabi-v7a, x86, arm64-v8a, x86_64

   if you're distributing your application, using the play store it's a good idea to do it with the Android app bundle.
2. Enabling prodguard will result in a lower size of the APK.
3. Optimize your image assets, and if there's a chance try using SVG assets as much a possible.

There have been a change in the size of the resulted APK in React-Native `0.62` by enabling the new JavaScript engine which reduce the size of the native libs almost **40%** [Hermes Engine](https://code.fb.com/android/hermes/)

These stats below are from Hermes engine and also mention the APK size reduction. 
[image]

Comment: I will be grateful if you give my some document and resource about your last sentence...(RN.62)

Answer (score 0):

```
release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    shrinkResources true
    ndk { 
        abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a" //this will help you to shrink your app size in release build
    }
}
```