# How to reduce the size of an expo/react-native app on Android

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing a small dictionary app by using react native with expo.

As I am compiling to Apk file. The size goes up to 30mb and after having installed on a device, it goes to 80mb.

Is this normal?

Are there any ways to reduce the size of the app?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you check the images ?

Comment: image is not above 1mb

Comment: this link is help you to resolve your problem [It will help you for shrink your app size (release build)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71923455/9294957)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

the expo is for development the app you should migrate to react-native for production

- make a new react app "`react-native init`"
- Copy the source files over from Expo project
- Install all dependencies of the Expo project except Expo specific libraries.
- Make necessary adjustments to `app.json` file
- Download the signing key of your Android app from Expo using exp
- fetch:android:keystore and set it up

This reduces your app dramatically you can also enable proguard and specific build for cpu architecture

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
```

for more info visit    https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640

### using expo component

after you done and want publish with less size or just wan't to use a native library expo give you an option called [ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/) this also can be used with already build with native code react projects

1-run command `expo eject` to add ExpoKit (choose the "ExpoKit" option)
(no need to do this if you have copied files manually or using native project)

2 -start expo packager with `expo start`.Leave this running and continue with the following steps.
3-
link library for android and ios, this command mostly do this `react-native link`, sometime this will not work and you should do it manually for this means visit [expokit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit)

PS: I didn't test this so if this not work inform me

Comment: It works great, reducing from 32mb to 9mb. And, even 7mb. Awesome.

Comment: It works great, reducing from 32mb to 9mb. And, even 7mb. Awesome. However, another problem is when it is installed on device, it goes up to 22mb. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i don't know how to reduce installed app size , and i will be glad to know, but in general app will be bigger cause apk is like compressed file

Comment: How can I use expo specific libraries in new project?

Comment: Please be more specific on how to do this: **Install all dependencies of the Expo project except Expo specific libraries**

Comment: Please reply When I need to use expo Asset or ImagePicker, Apploading then how do we use?

Comment: Wrong, Expo is not for app testing only. This answer doesn't work for those with Expo dependent libraries.

Comment: Instead of copying the source code from the existing expo project to another project I think its best to eject from expo and then build the apk using react-native build command

Answer (score 56):

For android APK bundle using expo, you can use the following command:

```
expo build:android -t app-bundle
```

The size will be much smaller *once you upload it to the play store*.
This is relevant for React Native SDK 32 and earlier.

Comment: This is by far the best answer - reduced my app from 47MB to 25MB a all that I had to do was to call a slightly different build command.

Comment: Yes, by far the best answer! My app went from 30MB to 12MB! Thank you!!! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: so the size will be the same on the expo build download? and then reduce on uploading to play store?

Comment: 25MB is also high

Comment: @rajithShetty did you get the answer ? will the size b same for expo build and then reduce on uploading to play store?

Comment: @rajithShetty command creates .aab bundle. You can upload it to your console and the resulting apk delivered to the device will be much smaller

Answer (score 13):

**Make following changes in `build.gradle` file located at:**

```
./android/app/build.gradle
```

Remove x86 from abi filters.

```
splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable true
            universalApk false
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

Generate different APK's for different architecture

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```

Enable ProGuard :

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

Also set minifyEnabled true and shrinkResources true

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

Also, you can have different build types for development and release builds(depends on your user base)

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
            ....
        }

        release {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            }
            ....
        }
```

**Also don't forget to remove the unused FONT Files**

Comment: we must need to define different version codes though (e.g. def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":18, "x86":19, "arm64-v8a": 20]). I failed multiple times to upload multiple apks due to this mistake.

Comment: Why should we remove `x86` form abi filters? is it not needed?

Comment: @VinilPrabhu did you get any reply?

Comment: @akshaygore When I remove x86, I get only an arm apk. I tried replaced "armeabi-v7a" with x86 and I get only an x86 build. I tried to have the two configrutaions in a single build.gradle and I am getting an error. Do you have an example for how to do that?

Comment: @Yossi i didn't find any answer to this, i have kept api filters as `"armeabi-v7a", "x86"`

Comment: @Yossi check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56928500/5895297)

Comment: This helped me (I am not using expo): https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23575#issuecomment-472726816

Comment: @Yossi If you don't want to support the Intel architectures or emulators then you can remove it.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2021, there is now a much easier option to reduce Android binary size, since ejecting/migrating to pure react-native, switching to bare workflow and building your own binaries locally requires a lot of work and study if you don't know how to do it already or don't have your environment and tools all set up.

In app.json, make the following changes:

```
"expo": {
...
  "android": {
    "enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true
  }
}
```

This alone should reduce app size in ~40-50% depending on your project.

There's a few things you should know about using this option, so you should read
https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/managed-app-size.md. It's still WAY easier than ejecting.

on top of that, you should still use app bundles (.aab) to get another ~50% size reduction after uploading to the play store:

`expo build:android -t app-bundle`

Comment: i have you this "enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true my app was 80mb and now it is 59mb

Comment: @SyedSadaifRizvi what version of expo SDK are you using? I tried the enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds set to true in SDK40 but the build fails

Comment: This actually broke my app. After adding this it only works in expo but crashes after adding to play store.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I guess that's why they put "dangerous" in the property name, probably it's a little unpredictable. I also believe it now is deprecated in favor of EAS builds, that allow a huge size reduction according to the documentation (haven't tried this yet)

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid copying the source code from the existing expo project to another project as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49993209/16750290)

If you use `eas build` (not `expo build`) you can try to set up `enableProguardInReleaseBuilds` param in `app.json`.

Example:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true,
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#pluginconfigtypeandroid

Comment: You have to install expo-build-properties for that : `npx expo install expo-build-properties`

Answer (score 2):

the other way to reduce your app size without manually copy-paste your code in another repo. In app.json or app.config.js just set it `enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds` to `true`, by doing this expo won't install the unnecessary node modules when you are running `expo build:android -t app-bundle`.

If you run into any crashes compare the native node modules which are installed before enabling `enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds` and install only the required one. You can find the native node modules installed in the `expo.io` build artefacts.

here are some node module that come along with managed flow which you may not require

expo-ads-admob:8.3.0
expo-analytics-amplitude:8.3.1
expo-ads-facebook:8.4.0
expo-analytics-segment:9.0.0
unimodules-constants-interface:5.3.0
expo-app-auth:9.2.0
expo-apple-authentication:2.2.1
unimodules-app-loader:1.3.0
unimodules-font-interface:5.3.0
unimodules-image-loader-interface:5.3.0
unimodules-permissions-interface:5.3.0
expo-application:2.3.0
expo-av:8.6.0
expo-background-fetch:8.5.0
expo-task-manager:8.5.0
unimodules-task-manager-interface:5.3.0
expo-barcode-scanner:9.0.0
unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface:5.3.0
expo-battery:3.0.0
expo-blur:8.2.0
expo-brightness:8.3.0
expo-calendar:8.5.0
expo-camera:9.0.0
unimodules-camera-interface:5.3.0
unimodules-face-detector-interface:5.3.0
unimodules-file-system-interface:5.3.0
expo-cellular:2.3.0
expo-constants:9.2.0
expo-contacts:8.5.0
expo-crypto:8.3.0
expo-device:2.3.0
expo-document-picker:8.4.0
expo-error-recovery:1.3.0
expo-face-detector:8.3.0
expo-facebook:9.0.0
expo-file-system:9.2.0
expo-firebase-analytics:2.5.0
expo-firebase-core:1.2.0
expo-font:8.3.0
expo-gl:9.1.1
expo-gl-cpp:9.1.2
expo-gl-cpp-legacy:8.4.0
expo-google-sign-in:8.3.0
expo-haptics:8.3.0
expo-image-loader:1.2.0
expo-image-manipulator:8.3.0
expo-image-picker:9.1.1
expo-permissions:9.3.0
expo-in-app-purchases:9.0.0
expo-intent-launcher:8.3.0
expo-keep-awake:8.3.0
expo-linear-gradient:8.3.0
expo-local-authentication:9.3.0
expo-localization:9.0.0
expo-location:9.0.0
expo-mail-composer:8.4.0
expo-media-library:9.2.1
expo-module-template:8.4.0
expo-network:2.3.0
expo-notifications:0.7.2
expo-payments-stripe:8.3.0
expo-print:9.1.0
expo-screen-capture:1.1.1
expo-screen-orientation:2.0.0
expo-secure-store:9.2.0
expo-sensors:9.1.0
unimodules-sensors-interface:5.3.0
expo-sharing:8.4.1
expo-sms:8.3.1
expo-speech:8.4.0
expo-splash-screen:0.6.2
expo-sqlite:8.4.0
expo-store-review:2.2.0
expo-updates:0.3.3
expo-video-thumbnails:4.3.0
expo-web-browser:8.5.0

Comment: Has anyone tested this?

Comment: yes i have tested and it reduce 15mb in my case . when i run expo:build android

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion will be for you to upgrade to EAS, with EAS your build size is reduced by more than 3/4, however, at this point, you have to pay $29 but I promise you it's worth it. An app I have been working on prompting into EAS reduced the bundle size from 80MB to 16MB. EAS also has EAS submit which enables you submit your app to the stores in a Flash

Comment: Not true, you can build through eas locally I described it it this "share the knowledge" Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592608/expo-build-eas Also I think there is (it may've been added later) a free tier - https://expo.dev/pricing

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade react-native to newer version, for different versions it is giving different size apk.

for `0.57` it was `≈12mb`

for `0.59.3` it was `≈30mb`

and for `0.59.9` it was `≈15mb`

always try to use updated react-native version

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options for reducing size of apk file from 32mb(expo) to 7mb(react-native cli).

1. Detach from expo
2. create new react-native cli project and copy all source from expo to new react-native project.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade expo version to 31.exporecently launched single-SDK builds for Android. These builds contain only the SDK version the app uses when built and are both faster and slimmer. it helps for smaller standalone app build size. [release note](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v31-0-0-is-now-available-cad6d0463f49)

Answer (score 0):

Vote over here so that expo can look into the feature https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/reducing-app-size Problem is react-native uses hermes so the packaging is similar to what native android app from android studio can do but since herme is like latest about 1-2year expo team has not made the support for hermes please vote.. And I also totally agree with @jakobinn