# React Native - why is my project folder taking up so much space?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react native project for a startup, but lately I have been noticing some perfomance issues running the Xcode simulator. There is not much animation at all, but simple movements like keyboard toggle are running painfully slow. I am running a brand new MacBook Air, and this issue certainly wasn't existent when the project began. My project takes up 1.25GB, with the `ios` folder taking up 844.3MB. Is this normal for what is right now a small project? Can I delete my `ModuleCache.noindex` (616.8MB) folder? Give me some ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you are trying to execute your project with Xcode simulator, before going to project size and particular details, can you check your simulator menu bar settings under debug -> slow animations option was enabled?, If Yes! just disable slow animation option and try to execute.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly it. Would have never thought there to be such an option! Thanks for that, but as for my project size, I still think it's too large. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Cool, to reduce RN project size, you can check out the existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-react-native-app-size as well as this blog too "https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640", hope this helps.