# I can't reduce the size of my React-Native Android App

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I created an android app (**React-Native**) that contains just 1 view (App.js) with some JS Script and two pictures (pictures size : 650 kb).

Can the installed packages by npm increase app size? even if it's not used in JS File?

So,why is my app having so much **large size (34.5 MB)** and also how can i even more reduce the size of my ReactNative AndroidApp.

Best Regards,

Comment: https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640

Comment: Yes.  Don't forget your app has to include all the framework of react native, and all the npm packages used in either the framework or the app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the react-native app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-react-native-app-size)