# react native signed apk size is 28.7 MB

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I am created my project using *react-native init* and when i am trying to create a signed apk the app size is *28.7 MB*. followed the  documentation the official site and some articles.

**pc specs:**
OS: Linux (elementory os)
processor: i5 8th gen
*(I was having the same issues in Ubuntu 18.10 and 18.4)*

*[I would appreciate if you try to help me solve this problem,
thank you for your time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljDZb.png)*

[apk analyzer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDyu.png)

Comment: What is issue apk size is large or anything else???

Comment: Sounds about right.  RN causes large apk sizes.  It includes an entire javascript interpreter

Comment: It shouldn't be that bigger. I don't know what is this project about. But in my experience, it should be around 8-13 MB. Using Split APKs by ABI it can be reduced more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the react-native app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-react-native-app-size)