# Too large react-native release apk

Tags: android, gradle, apk, react-native

Created a release apk for blank react native app, after analyzing the apk, found that lib folder takes 25mb by default, is there any way this size can be reduced for universal apk ?[image]

what i did : Created project using **react-native-cli** and not **EXPO**, was expecting lesser size based on google search, but got this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the react-native app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-react-native-app-size)

Comment: tried that but it says app is 7mb, but for me i am getting at least 27mb

Comment: Will retract close vote if you update your question with what you've tried in detail.

Comment: @MorrisonChang done

Comment: Retracted, recommend that you list out what is in the libs directory and see if you want to exclude x86/x64 ABI. Only current x86/x64 devices for Android would be Chromebooks (ARC++ has ARM translation layer, and ChromeOS may not be your target audience)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the play store react-native apps size (like **airbnb**, **instagram**)  you will find out that all of react-native apps size are over 30 MB and it's normal for React-native apps to be much heavier than native apps.
You can use **react-native-cli** instead of expo, your app size at first will be about 17 MB, It's much better i think. isn't it?

You can try this too to make it smaller.
see [this post on medium](https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640)

Comment: I am using **react-native-cli** only, still app size is always 25mb(lib) + project code