# How to reduce apk or aab file size in react native using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have just started react native with expo. My first app has only one App.js file and one component of counter. When I have built it, surprisingly my apk size was 49MB :open_mouth: I wonder why its so and how to reduce it without ejecting???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expo is purely for development purpose** , and its only recommended for production if your app is very basic and doesnt have much of native functionalities. Even expo is slower and has much limitations. The larger size of expo is due to the **expo wrapper which sits on top of react native** , which has a lot of in built modules and thus making it larger.

**Recommendation**: If you want to lower the apk size , you should migrate to pure `react native` as expo doesnt give the power of actually decreasing the app size since its handled by expo.

You can even check this link [expo -size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-expo-react-native-app-on-android) which also had the same query .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gaurav Roy is right. you should create a new project using ```react native init``` & add only the dependencies/modules that you need.

Comment: yeah it served the purpose. thanks for your response.... Now i need to keep developing using expo and in the end its better to eject in order to reduce the app size.