# Why is my react native apk size so big? And what can I do to reduce it?

Tags: apk, react-native, expo

I created an app which I created using Expo, so I had all the files generated by them. But when I build the apk of my app which then I have to download from the expo server, it's size is more than 40 mb which is too high given that my app displays data using firebase and I have developed apps more complex than this which are around just 10mbs or so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-expo-react-native-app-on-android see this

Answer (score 0):

### Why is my react native apk size so big?

The larger size of expo is due to Expo wrapper which sits on top of react native. It has few built-in modules which are not always required by the app but are included by default

### What can I do to reduce it?

1. You can eject from  Expo to pure react native via `expo eject` OR
2. **For Expo SDK version 41+ managed workflow:** They have introduced **EAS (Expo Application Services)** for managed workflow in sdk version 41 and it can reduce app size to even **10x** smaller.

About EAS:
https://blog.expo.io/eas-build-april-preview-update-ebd7dff9dd25

This is how you will build your expo app using EAS:
https://docs.expo.io/build/setup/