# Switch from Expo to bare React native

Tags: react-native, expo

After giving the command `expo build:android` to generate .apk file for my project. The size of the app was too big (60MB). So, I went through certian websites, Most of them are showing that I need to eject expo and generate an apk in bare react-native-cli. Is there any method to reduce the size of an expo app? or should I go with bare react-native-cli. If it is a yes, can you provide steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Cross answering from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937246/8196025). In your app.json make the following changes

```
"expo": {
...
  "android": {
    "enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true
  }
}
```

And you can use

```
expo build:android -t app-bundle
```

This will create an Android Application Bundle which is a publishing format.