# How to reduce app size using Expo - React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

- I'm currently using  the new Expo SDK 42.0.0
- My app is complete but is around 130 MB.
- How can I reduce the app size?

Warning: I have a lot of images and sqlite database connection on this app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Do following things for reduce app size :

1. Remove images from app and store it on server and load it from there if it will lazy to show when screen is open
2. Use icon instead of images for icons
3. Remove unnecessary packages that have added for single purpose only.

More information you can find on this link : [how to reduce RN-app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993006/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-expo-react-native-app-on-android)