# Expo build EAS - local - SDK location not found

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-build, expo-eas

When I used the new build tool from expo called [EAS](https://docs.expo.dev/eas/) to build my react native application locally:

`eas build --platform android --local`

I got an error:

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

All the answers I've found are suggesting creating file `local.properties` in an `android` directory and setting the `sdk.dir` in it, this is however related to the old build tool `expo build`... another option is to simply define the environmental variable on the system level which I tried to avoid.

So I was wondering how to do it in some type of configuration file still local to the react native project. I found the answer by accident, so I'm sharing the knowledge below

By the way, if you're looking for where is the default build path of the final bundle - it's most likely dumped into the project root (don't forget to refresh files if you need to).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## TL;DR

Project root `eas.json` => `build` => `production` => `"env": { "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT": "/path/to/AndroidSDK" }`

### Step 1: find path to your Android SDK

The problem in general is that the EAS build is missing path to Android SDK, so first you need to find the correct path,
***Android SDK does not have to be in the default path***
but if you have it in one of the following, you can **take it and jump to step 2** (*replace `YourUserName` with your username*):

**Windows:** `C:\\Users\\YourUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`

**Mac:** `/Users/YourUserName/Library/Android/sdk`

**Linux:** `/home/YourUserName/Android/Sdk`

*On some systems, the paths may be case-sensitive => copy them as-they-are from system*

I personally for example have SDK on a bigger HDD elswhere. Don't know the path but still have Android Studio? => try looking for *"Android SDK" in "System Settings"* in settings/configuration - *Configure => Settings => Appearance & Behavior* (or maybe you have it under *Preferences*). Don't have Android Studio anymore/path there is not valid? => you're left with brute force searching for "android*" in folders like "tools", "build-tools", "emulator", but you may be better off with just installing the SDK into a new
location :-)

## Step 2: configure in `eas.json`

Depending on your target build (I assume `production` ) you want to define the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environmental variable for the target build under `env` JSON key in `eas.json`. The `eas.json` should be in your ***react native project root folder*** - for example on the same level as `src` or `.expo` folders *usually* are.

Example `eas.json` on Linux/Ubuntu:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.49.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
        "env": {
            "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT": "/home/YourUserName/Android/Sdk"
        }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Change/keep `cli` version according to your project.

Comment: Also I will take the liberty and mention, that after all this pain and references from other developers, I started focusing more on "Flutter" - it uses a C-like language of its own Dart - but it's very similar to Java/C++/PHP or even JavaScript - it may save you some pain if you're still at the begining :-)

Comment: Props for giving cross-platform advice. You are a role model.