# A problem occured evaulating project ':expo'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, build, expo

I've got this exception when I try to build locally to android eas build --local. How can I fix it?

eas-build-local-nodejs/6d58e91b-2d03-4868-bb8c-bd07da09061f/build/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 356
        [RUN_GRADLEW] * What went wrong:
        [RUN_GRADLEW] A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
        [RUN_GRADLEW] >
        [RUN_GRADLEW] A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
        [RUN_GRADLEW] > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
        [RUN_GRADLEW]       > SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file

I use gradle 8, expo 49.
These are my dependencies in the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex": "^7.16.7",
        "@expo/config": "~8.1.1",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.28.0",
        "@types/node": "^13.11.0",
        "@types/react-native-tab-view": "^2.3.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
        "@use-expo/font": "^2.0.0",
        "@amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.6",
        "@aws-amplify": "^4.3.4",
        "aws-amplify-react-native": "^5.0.3",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1022.0",
        "expo": "^49.0.0",
        "expo-background-fetch": "~11.3.0",
        "expo-build-properties": "^0.8.3",
        "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
        "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
        "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
        "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
        "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
        "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
        "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
        "expo-task-manager": "~11.3.0",
        "expo-tracking-transparency": "~3.1.0",
        "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
        "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
        "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.5",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
        "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
        "react-native-email-link": "^1.14.1",
        "react-native-gallery-swiper": "^1.26.4",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
        "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
        "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
        "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.7.1",
        "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
        "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.6",
        "react-native-mime-types": "^2.3.0",
        "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
        "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
        "react-native-purchases": "5.0.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
        "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "0.9.1",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
        "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "sentry-expo": "^7.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
        "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
        "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.0",
        "audit-ci": "^6.6.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-preset-expo": "^9.5.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.8.1",
        "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.11",
        "ghooks": "^2.0.4",
        "jest": "^29.2.1",
        "prettier": "^2.0.2",
        "ts-jest": "24.0.0",
        "typescript": "^5.1.3"
}
```

This is the eas.json

```
{
    "cli": {
            "version": ">= 0.1.0"
     },
     "build": {
            "development": {
                    "developmentClient": true,
                    "distribution": "internal",
                    "channel": "development"
            },
            "preview": {
                    "distribution": "internal"
            },
            "production": {
                    "ios": {
                            "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
                    },
                    "android": {
                            "buildType": "apk"
                    },
                    "env": {
                            "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT": "/Home/Sdk",
                            "GOOGLE_SERVICES_FILE": "./google-service.json"
                    }
            }
    },
    "submit": {
            "production": {}
    }
}
```

I try to run expo doctor to figure out what is the problem but it doesn't help.

Comment: Is expo-modules-core installed in your project?

Comment: Now I installed it, but the exception is still there

Comment: If you've updated your expo version since building the app, there was a change in the string to the sdk location. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592608/expo-build-eas-local-sdk-location-not-found

Comment: Yes, the expo version was 45 before. We got the project from the previous developer. He can build it. The expo repo was changed and the backend is was amplify.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @nageennayak I added eas.json to my description.

Answer (score 0):

Your eas cli version is outdated, right now eas version is >5, refer to this doc to update `https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/`. Delete your eas.json folder and install using the above document. Also try downgrading your expo in package.json to `~48.0.10`. This might help in moving towards solving your problem.

Comment: I followed the steps but unfortunately, the error is still on.